# How do I go about conducting model diagnostics on WLS?

Tags: r, modeling, poisson-regression, diagnostic

I'm familiar with the diagnostics required for OLS, however I'm in new territory with a model I'm fitting to data in R, using Poisson regression with GLM.

What are the standard methods in evaluating a WLS model?

Comment: Why are you fitting a Poisson model using weighted least squares rather than maximum likelihood?

Comment: @onestop comment still applies, but maybe your question is how in general GLM models should be interpreted compared to OLS models?